# What's the difference between firebase cloud messaging & firebase notifications?

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

in the new Firebase 3.0, i am trying to get my head around when to use Firebase Cloud messaging and when to use Firebase Notifications.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Firebase Cloud Messaging** is the library that you need to use in your application to receive cloud messages.
It includes client APIs (multi-platform) to receive messages, and server APIs (HTTP and XMPP) to send messages.

**Firebase Notifications** is the tool integrated in the Firebase Console to schedule cloud messages. This also includes the integration with Firebase Analytics to target analytics-based audiences and track opening and conversion events.

Hope this will help to understand the difference :)

Comment: is there any examples of how to use FCM?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging  check this one out. It's easy to understand.